# Netlify Identity redirects me to my production URL when I log in locally

Tags: netlify

I have a Next.js (React) app running locally with `netlify dev`.

I use the Netlify Identity with the [netlify-identity-widget](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-identity-widget).

I can successfully log in, however, I always get redirected to my remote/production URL when I click on the "Login in" button in the modal.

**Any ideas why my app does not stay at localhost?**

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the redirection only happens when I log in with an external provider. For development, I created a new account and now I don't get redirected anymore. This is fine for my development.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer as to why this occurs, but I believe I have a more complete idea of how to work with this situation.

When you get redirected to your production URL upon login, the URL will have login information appended to the URL, e.g.

```
https://<my-production-url>/#access_token=<hash>&expires_in=3600&refresh_token=<hash>&token_type=bearer
```

Copy all the information starting with `/#` and append it to your local URL (with port), e.g.

```
https://localhost:8888/#access_token=<hash>&expires_in=3600&refresh_token=<hash>&token_type=bearer
```

Note: You have to force a page load. If you append this to an existing tab in Chrome, it will not reload the page.

This works because the Netlify Identity Widget looks for that information in the URL on page load.

This same trick also works for the Email Confirmation link, which will forward you to your production URL with a hash that looks like this:

```
/#confirmation_token=<hash>
```

But you might not experience the same issue with the email confirmation piece if you already had the Netlify Identity Widget deployed to your production site.

I figured this all out from reading this [Netlify forum thread](https://answers.netlify.com/t/common-issue-netlify-cms-git-gateway-email-not-confirmed/10690/6)